# How to switch org-babel-execute-src-block to use y-or-n-p?

Tags: org-babel, prompt

In short, I want org-babel's prompt to accept a single y/n keypress instead of typing it out and pressing enter, but I don't want to replace all such prompts globally.

I've seen information on changing to y-or-n-p as the global [default via defalias](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/YesOrNoP), or turning off the prompt specific to org-babel completely via org-confirm-babel-evaluate, but not how to simply shorten the prompt.  I see notes on yes-or-no.el for making functions customizable, but it doesn't seem like that applies to org-babel.

In this particular case (imho), it's important enough to preserve the prompt, but not important enough to justify typing 4 characters to do so each time.

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yes-or-no-p` is hard-coded into `org-babel-confirm-evaluate`.
We override it with `y-or-n-p` locally for `org-babel-confirm-evaluate`:

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'cl-lib))

(defun org+-substitute-yes-or-no-p (fun &rest args)
  "Run FUN with ARGS and `yes-or-no-p' locally substituted by `y-or-n-p'."
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'yes-or-no-p) #'y-or-n-p))
    (apply fun args)))

(advice-add 'org-babel-confirm-evaluate :around #'org+-substitute-yes-or-no-p)
```

Note, that I also tried to set `org-confirm-babel-evaluate` to the function

```el
(lambda (_lang _body)
  (unless (y-or-n-p "Evaluate source block? ")
    (signal 'quit '("Evaluation of source block aborted"))))
```

But that does not work nicely. It asks twice for `y-or-n-p` confirmation for each code block.

Tested with `emacs -Q` of version 26.3.

Comment: That worked perfectly for regular emacs. Confusingly I just noticed that on Aquamacs [on a different machine with same .emacs.el] it does this by default.